# How do select all checkbox within iteam renderer data grid using flex?

Tags: apache-flex, web-applications, air, flash

In my project I used one **select all button** for select all checkbox at click event. But I used datagrid, item renderer within checkbox so no id of checkbox then how to select/unselect all checkbox ?

```
<mx:DataGrid id=newdatagrid>
<mx:columns>

<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="1"  rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="selected">
                                <mx:itemRenderer>
                                    <mx:Component>
<mx:CheckBox click="{data.check1 = (data.check1 != 'true') ? 'true' : 'false'};outerDocument.toggleCheckbox(data);outerDocument.calcValues();" dataChange="this.selected=outerDocument.validateCheckbox(data)"/>
                    </mx:Component>
                                            </mx:itemRenderer>
                                </mx:DataGridColumn>

                    </mx:columns>
                </mx:DataGrid>
```

How can I implement select/unselect all button for checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, bind the selected property of your checkbox in the itemrenderer to the "check1" property of your dataprovider items:

```
<mx:CheckBox selected="{data.check1}"/>
```

Then set the "check1" property of each item in the dataprovider in response to a button click.

```
for each (var item:Object in dataProvider) {
  item.check1 = true; // or false;
}
```